# cannot install firebase functions using npm

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to install the firebase cloud functions using npm install firebase-functions I get this error.

```
apples-MBP:functions litsonthomas$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:51497
npm ERR! 3","cookie":"0.0.3","crc":"0.2.0","fresh":"0.1.0","methods":"0.0.1","
npm ERR!                                                                          ^

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/litsonthomas/.npm/_logs/2017-08-09T17_17_40_233Z-
debug.log
apples-MBP:functions litsonthomas$
```

Any ideas why this is happening?!

Thank You!

Comment: can you show the content of your package.json

Comment: try to update your node

Comment: Fixed the problem!
Cleaned the npm cache and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

run as cmd admin, npm install firebase --force